# PowerApps builder not reflecting updates made to a custom connector

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I'm starting to use PowerApps for a demo project and I am exploring the capabilities to leverage this in front of a custom API I have running in Azure.

I created a custom connector, by importing the Swagger file (only v2 supported, btw).  And after that, I quickly was able to start to use this connector from a Canvas app.

However, after updating some schemas/types in the Custom Connector designer (added a few fields), these changes don't get reflected in the App builder.  When trying to actually make the call with these new parameters, I also get an error.

So, I'm wondering what has to happen in order to update/refresh the custom connector in the app builder?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If an app requires the changes made in a custom connector, you need to remove the connector from the app and re-add it. This should bring in the changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you changed the schema of the response, you likely need to update response in the Custom Connector before you can call the new parameters.

- Go to the Custom Connector
- Then `Definition` then `Response` and select `Add Default Response`
- Paste in the new schema along with any headers
- Test it
- When good, proceed

[image]

From here things can be tricky.

**In the past I've had to:**

- Create a new connection
- Remove the Custom Connector from the app

  - Save and publish
- Reopen the app
- Readd the Custom Connector
- Save, Publish and CLOSE
- Reopen the app, select `Allow`
- Proceed.

Custom connectors (like Sharepoint lists and Flows) can be tricky to "refresh" once PowerApps has a set schema.